# Python 3.11: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

I'm writing local transform for Maltego where I need to first receive data from API in utf-8 and then send it to Maltego in cp1251.

I do something like:

```
some_txt_var = txt_from_api.encode("utf-8", "strict").decode("cp1251", "strict")
```

and it works just fine for everything except one cyrillic charachter "И" - Capital Cyrillic I.

Code to illustrate the problem:

```
byte1 = "З".encode("utf-8", "strict")
byte2 = "Й".encode("utf-8", "strict")
byte3 = "І".encode("utf-8", "strict")
byte4 = "И".encode("utf-8", "strict")

print(byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4)
```

Result:
b'\xd0\x97' b'\xd0\x99' b'\xd0\x86' b'\xd0\x98'

```
text1 = byte1.decode("cp1251", "strict")
text2 = byte2.decode("cp1251", "strict")
text3 = byte3.decode("cp1251", "strict")

print(text1, text2, text3)
```

Result in target application:
З Й І

```
text4 = byte4.decode("cp1251", "strict")
```

raises an error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

Can anybody suggest solution or workaround?

I have tried to "force" Maltego, which runs in Java Virtual Machine to accept utf-8 insted of cp1251 by setting `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8` in Windows System Variables, but with no success.

So far I'm temporarily using `.decode("cp1251", "replace")` and get special `\ufffd` - Replacement Character instead of "И" сharacter, while all other chars are absolutely OK.

Update: I've managed to "force" Maltego to accept utf-8 encoded strings by changing Windows system language settings.
On Windows 10 computer:
Language settings >> Administrative language settings >> Change system language >> beta:use unicode (utf-8).
This is a workaround rather than a solution since potential users often use Windows machines without the possibility to change language settings due to the necessity to keep cp1251 for the other legacy software depending on this encoding.

Still puzzled by the exceptional treatment of "Cyrillic Capital I" by the Python decoder and will greatly appreciate advice on possible solutions.

Comment: Your unnatural approach is exactly how a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) works.  Just send all  to Maltego _unaltered_…

Comment: Tried that. All non-Latin characters are replaced with \ufffd. Didn't know that there is a whole subject on Wikipedia :)